# how to create instance of a concret class which has used an abstract class and that abstract class implemented an interface

Tags: c#, oop

I Have two blow interface

```
public interface ITargetManager: ITargetManager<TargetManager, Target>
{

}

public interface ITargetManager<TSelf, T>
   where TSelf : TargetManager<TSelf,T>
   where T : Target
{
    int Prop1 { get; }
    string Prop2 { get; }
    int? Prop3 { get; }
    string Prop4 { get; }

    T Build();
    void Update(T target);
    TSelf WithProp1(int value);
    TSelf WithProp2(string value);
    TSelf WithProp3(int? value);
    TSelf WithProp4(string value);
}
```

and below abstract class has used that interface:

```
public abstract class TargetManager<TSelf, T>
   : ITargetManager<TSelf, T>
    where TSelf : TargetManager<TSelf, T>
    where T : Target
{
    private int prop1;
    private string prop2;
    private int? prop3;
    private string prop4;
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> dic = new();
    public TargetManager(T? target = null)
    {
        if (target == null) return;

        WithProp1(target.Prop1);
        WithProp2(target.Prop2);
        WithProp3(target.Prop3);
        WithProp4(target.Prop4);
    }
    public int Prop1 => prop1;

    public string Prop2 => prop2;

    public int? Prop3 => prop3;

    public string Prop4 => prop4;

    public TSelf WithProp1(int value)
    {
        prop1 = value;
        return this;
    }

    public TSelf WithProp2(string value)
    {
        prop2 = value;
        return this;
    }

    public TSelf WithProp3(int? value)
    {
        prop3 = value;
        return this;
    }

    public TSelf WithProp4(string value)
    {
        prop4 = value;
        return this;
    }

    public T Build() => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this)!;

    public void Update(T target)
    {
        var methodInfo = dic.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), getUpdateMethodInfo);
        methodInfo.Invoke(target, new object[] { this });
    }

    private static MethodInfo getUpdateMethodInfo(Type optionType)
    {
        var types = getInheritanceHierarchy(typeof(T));
        var methods = typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(mi => mi.Name == "Update");
        return types.Join(
            methods, t => t.Name,
            mi => mi.DeclaringType.Name,
            (t, mi) => mi)
            .First();

    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> getInheritanceHierarchy(Type type)
    {
        for (var current = type; current != null; current = current.BaseType)
        {
            yield return current;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator TSelf(TargetManager<TSelf, T> builder)
    {
        return (TSelf)builder;
    }


    //public void Update(T target)
    //{
    //    var getMethodInfo = dic.GetOrAdd(typeof(TOption), getUpdateMethodInfo);
    //    getMethodInfo.Invoke(target, new object[] { this });
    //}


    //private static MethodInfo getUpdateMethodInfo(Type optionsType)
    //{
    //    return typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    //         .Single(mi => mi.Name == "Update" && mi.GetParameters()
    //         .Any(p => p.ParameterType == optionsType));
    //}

}
```

finally another class has used that abstract class

```
public class TargetManager : TargetManager<TargetManager, Target>
{
    public TargetManager(Target? target = null) : base(target)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to create instance of that class.

```
sutManager = new TargetManager();
```

but it will not work and I got below error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'BuilderTest.TargetManager' to 'BuilderTest.ITargetManager'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) BuilderTest C:\Users\S.monzavi\source\repos\BuilderTest\BuilderTest\UnitTest1.cs    16  Active

Comment: What is the type of `sutManager`? Because `var sutManager = new TargetManager();` just works.

Comment: private readonly ITargetManager sutManager;

        public UnitTest1(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
        {
            //sutManager = new TargetManager();

             }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception message `sutManager` is `ITargetManager`, i.e. something like:

```cs
ITargetManager sutManager = new TargetManager();
```

But `TargetManager` does not implement `ITargetManager`, so this assignment is invalid, change the `TargetManager` to:

```cs
public class TargetManager : TargetManager<TargetManager, Target>, ITargetManager
```

Another approach is to remove `ITargetManager` interface and specify the alias on the top at the file:

```cs
using ITargetManager = ITargetManager<TargetManager, Target>;
```